# How to create an ajax request and a background animation simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this piece of code:

```
    $('#contentSites').fadeOut(200, function() {
        // Animation complete
            $.get("my_account_content.php?q=" + content, function(data){
                $("div#contentSites").html(data);
                $('#contentSites').fadeIn(200);
});
```

I have 2 buttons that activates the ajax request and changes the whole content of #contentSites - right now it does 3 things one by one (only executes the next one until the previous one is finished). It does this:
1. fade out the current content
2. get the new content
3. fade in the new content.

Since this is not highly efficient (since that I need to wait until the fadeout happens before the ajax request).

**I wanted to ask how to fire simultaneously the fadeout and the ajax request and only when the ajax request has finished to do the fade in.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would simply remove the callback on fadeOut

```
$('#contentSites').fadeOut(200);
$.get("my_account_content.php?q=" + content, function(data){
    $("div#contentSites").html(data);
    $('#contentSites').fadeIn(200);
});
```

Another way to do it using jQuery [defferds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) would be

```
$.when( $('#contentSites').fadeOut(200), get_content() ).then(function(){ 
    $('#contentSites').fadeIn(200);
}); 

function get_content(){
   return $.get("my_account_content.php?q=" + content, function(data){
             $("div#contentSites").html(data);
          });
}
```

This will ensure that fadeIn is only run after *both* the ajax request *and* the fadeOut have finished, while running both simultaneously.

Comment: but what if the content has been received really fast before the fade out finished executing?

Comment: Alon, look at my edit if you want to synchronize them but still have them run simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
$('#contentSites').fadeOut(200);

$.get("my_account_content.php?q=" + content, function(data){
    $("div#contentSites").html(data);
    $('#contentSites').fadeIn(200);
});
```